# How to use the equivalent of "fill" and "color" in R, in Python?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, seaborn, histogram

I have been following the "Doing Data Science" Handbook and here is the code that I have to plot the distributions of impressions with respect to six categories that I created for Age brackets.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data1, aes(x=Impressions, fill=agecat))+geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
```

In Python, to plot the histogram of Impressions vs the age category, I used seaborn. I tried to use legend, but the code here is plotting only one category (35-50). I am not sure why. Could someone help?

Sorry, I am not able to embed the plots because I do not have have much reputation. I have added them here in these links, please check them out.

[R plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsDW8.jpg)

[Python plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50OWi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that we can add the attribute as hue in the sns.countplot

Here is how I did it:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(x = "Impressions",hue = "age_group",data=data1 )
```

[Find the plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Bio.png)

Or, I can use the same customized ggplot in Python Plotnine.